# Very DInamic Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Today i'm strugle with this layout requirement.

```
| textviewX icon textviewY                   textviewZ |
| longlonglonglong_textviewX… icon textviewY textviewZ |
| textviewX icon longlonglonglong_textviewY… textviewZ |
| longlon_textviewX… icon longlon_textviewY… textviewZ |
| textviewX icon textviewY  longlonglonglong_textviewZ |
```

I have textViewX icon and textViewY that should be place in one section aligned to left and textviewZ that aligned to right.

That's is the scenario, 5 different condition.

- first one if all text is short,
- second if the textviewX is long,
- third if textviewY is long,
- fourth if textviewX and textviewY is long
- and fifth if textviewZ is long and textviewX and textviewY is short.

.... mean it elipsed.

I tried different approach using guideline and or app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed" but no luck.

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="96dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/from_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/iv_arrow"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        tools:text="Long Long Long Long" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/from_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/=to_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/from_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/=from_name"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/to_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iv_arrow"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_status"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Longlonglong longlong" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline_status"
    tools:text="statussssssss" />
```

Comment: Have you tried `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="..."`? This allows you to distribute the free space on a line evenly between the individual gaps (or in a ratio of 2:1:2, for example)?